# How to find all occurences of a word that's preceded by a number/decimal/fraction

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can match characters that are preceded by a number (integer, decimal or fraction) plus 0 or more spaces

e.g.

```
$str1="12.5km of road";
$str2="1/2 mile";
$str3="1 l milk";
```

In the case of $str1, for example, I need something like:

```
$searchString="km";
preg_match("/THE_REGEX_I_NEED".$searchString."/", $str1, $arrayOfMatches);
```

I'm not competent with writing regex, so any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str1="12.5km of road";
if (preg_match_all('~\d+(?:[/.]\d+)?\s*(\S+)~', $str1, $arr))
   print_r($arr[1]);
```

**EDIT:** To match only known strings use this code:

```
$str1="2 miles of road in 50 states";
if (preg_match_all('~\d+(?:[/.]\d+)?\s*(miles|km)\b~', $str1, $arr))
print_r($arr[1]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => miles
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of adapting this to only match a given $searchString that meets this condition? Your code seems to match ANY string that occurs after a number/decimal/fraction.

Comment: What is the condition? You asked to **`match characters that are preceded by a number (integer, decimal or fraction) plus 0 or more spaces`**

Comment: That is the condition, but I want to specify the characters as well. For example:
if my searchstring is "miles",
"2 miles of road in 50 states" should match "2 miles", but not "50 states".